# Sending URL to ISAPI module in IIS

Tags: iis, isapi

So I have an ISAPI module running my website. I would like to get the URL to be forwarded to my ISAPI module so that it can parse it and display things accordingly. For example, if I navigate to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), I wish for my app to run. This does occur. However, I would like to navigate to [www.mydomain.com/page1](http://www.mydomain.com/page1) and for my module to receive the "/page1" portion of the URL, which it does not. Rather, ISAPI complains because it cannot find the file "C:\where\I\have\my\app\deployed\to\page1".

I currently have my ISAPI module configured to run matching "/". If I configure it to run matching "*", it does not complain about not being able to find the file "page1" but instead treats anything I put into the URL as matching the module's request path and instead passes no URL information to the module.

I am uncertain what logs or settings would be useful to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Why do you need an ISAPI module? Nobody should write one, as a managed module exposes all necessary items to you in C#, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net and much easier to debug (just attach a .NET debugger).

Comment: @LexLi I'm not using C#.

Comment: Then you should learn it. ISAPI was the legacy API from pre-2000, so nobody seriously uses that today.

Comment: Already know it.
I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone has an answer, but if not, then I'll ditch the IIS approach.

Comment: @Altainia it looks HTTPExtensionProc is how the ISAPI code can get information about the request from IIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525010(v=vs.90)

Comment: That function has a EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK param, which has a bunch of stuff about the request including path info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525658(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0):

ISAPI Filters are introduced in IIS 6, and not recommended any more since IIS 7. However, there might exists legacy code which needs to be maintained. So here is the [guide](https://zzz.buzz/2017/12/08/developing-and-debugging-isapi-filters/#troubleshooting) to develop, troubleshoot and debug ISAPI Filters. But there is not a lot of documentation for this module to help.